# How to use mvvmcross core library in Windows Service project?

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

I have a developed a WPF project using mvvmcross library and now I want to use the core part in windows service project. Can someone please give a pointer to start with this? Basically I want to implement Setup.cs for the windows service project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MvvmCross does not support Windows Service projects. Nor do we have any intentions of adding support currently. Nor do I understand why you would even use it there, unless it is for the IoC it provides.

You can take a look at how the Console version is implemented. You can probably copy it straight and it will work for Windows Services too.
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/4.0/MvvmCross/Console/Console

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, I am looking to use the services written from the core project.